# Assign matched item in list to a variable

Tags: python-3.x

**The motive is to check if any of items in a list are contained in another list, and in case there is a match, assign it to a variable in a 'pythonic' fashion**

```
if any('a','b','c') in ['b','x','y','z']:
    #now i want to assign the matched 'b' to a variable concisely. 
    #In case of multiple matches , any match/ first match may be assigned
```

**I want to avoid this :**

```
lst = ['b','x','y','z']
if 'a' in lst:
    var = 'a'
elif 'b' in lst"
    var = 'b'
# and so on
```

Comment: I doubt that the first snippet is doing what you expect it to do unless you forgot to add some parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that returns either the first matched element or `None` in case no matched elements are found:

```
li_1 = ['a','b','c']
li_2 = ['b','x','y','z']

def find(li_1, li_2):
    for e in li_1:
        if e in li_2:
            return e

print(find(li_1, li_2))
# b
print(find(['a'], ['b']))
# None
```

**Note** that this is an O(n^2) solution. If the items are hashable you can get an O(1) solution using sets intersection (and as a bonus you will get *all* matched elements):

```
li_1 = ['a','b','c']
li_2 = ['b','x','y','z']

s1 = set(li_1)
s2 = set(li_2)
print(s1.intersection(s2))  # or print(s1 & s2)
# {'b'}
```